# Access typedef as non-static member of class?

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

Basically, what I want to do is something like this:

```
template<typename x,typename y,typename z>
struct SomeTemplateClass {
 typedef x myType;
};
```

then...

```
SomeTemplateClass<LongVariableNames,ILikePie,AndCheese> cheese;
cheese.myType i;
```

So `i` will have the type `LongVariableNames`.

I know it's probably bad practice to do stuff like this, but I just want to know. What's the simplest way to do something like this?

I mean, it should be possible to resolve this at compile time easily, because of the strong static typing and such. It would be useful to have a `typeof()` thing just like `sizeof()`.

Comment: Staticity isn't an issue here, since `myType` is a member *type*, not a member *value*.

Comment: Where is defined `cheese.type`? Maybe is it `cheese.myType`?

Comment: But the `myType` of a `SomeTemplateClass<LongVariableNames,ILikePie,AndCheese>` is always gonna be `LongVariableNames`, right?

Comment: Alessandro Pezzato, yeah, sorry. I fixed that.

Comment: typo: `typename y, typename x` -> `typename y, typename z` I suppose

Comment: "*I know it's probably bad practice to do stuff like this, but I just want to know.*" Actually, this is _good_ practice for generic programming, and very common. However, C++11 has different idioms that obviate the need for this in general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically it goes like this:

```
typedef SomeTemplateClass<LongVariableNames,ILikePie,AndCheese> foodType;

foodType cheese;

foodType::myType i;
```

In C++11 you could also use `decltype(cheese)::myType`, but that's very ugly.

Comment: And if you don't have direct access to `foodType` you can always get it as a template argument wherever you use `cheese`. e.g. `template <typename T> void useCheese(const T& cheese) { T::myType i; }`

Comment: Nice, but you see, I'm actually implementing a macro, and I want to be able to get a type of a variable to declare and use in that macro. So this doesn't work for me, sorry.

Comment: @myrkos: Don't use macros. Macros are evil. They wreak havoc with the type system.

Comment: @myrkos: In that case, what you have _is_ the simplist.

Comment: @MooingDuck, perhaps, but last time I tried to compile it the compiler refused it.

Comment: @myrkos: I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish; I suggest you post your larger, overall goal as a separate question along with your attempts at solving it and ask for design recommendations.

Comment: Kerrek, I don't really care if macros are evil, I'm just wondering about the actual language specification. Why doesn't it allow such things, and why not have a `typeof` compiler directive just like the `sizeof`? Is it because they're afraid of bad code?

Comment: @myrkos: The C++11 standard does: `decltype(cheese)::myType`

Comment: @myrkos: well, we do have that in C++11.

Comment: Oh, yes, indeed it does. Thanks, I didn't see that.